# How to specify the result type of useParams with react router v6?

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom

With react router v5, to specify the result type of useParams, I used:

```
const { param1, param2 } = useParams<{ param1: string, param2: string }>();
```

How can I do that with react router v6?

I cannot figure out how to type more than 1 parameter (e.g.: `useParams<"param1">()`) and I cannot figure out how to type the param as `string` and not `string | undefined` (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992370/why-react-router-v6-useparams-returns-object-with-properties-possibly-undefined)).

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for the same thing, and after looking into typings of useParams I figured out that you need to pass keys of params as strings like:

```
const { param1 } = useParams<'param1'>();
```

If you want multiple params just use typescript's `|` like in the example below.

```
type Params = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
// ...
const params = useParams<Params>();
```

The returned object's values will always have type of `string | undefined` because of react router typings.

```
export declare type Params<Key extends string = string> = {
    readonly [key in Key]: string | undefined;
};
```

But at the end of the day you can always use typescript's `as`

```
interface Params {
    a: string;
}

const params = useParams<keyof Params>() as Params;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version (6.14.1), you can use types instead of interfaces.

```
type Params {
    a: string;
}

const params = useParams<Params>();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).